# WCF silverlight application does not access from the WAN

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, tcp

We developed an application in Silverlight / C # / WCF.
Used in our service, custom binding.
The service implements methods beyond DUPLEX CRUD methods with the TCP protocol.

Due to the net, owning our endpoint URL: net.tcp://localhost:4502/Aplicacao/ncServico.svc"

Everything works on an intranet on port 80.
Now, did the port 8080 NAT router and configure IIS to port 8080 and we want to access the application from another network.

In the test we are using a 3G modem; typed into the browser: :8080/Aplication/

We arrived at the home screen of the application, but the service is not called by the application.
I can see the WSDL of the service on our application does not see the service.

Understand: there is no error, just the service was not found by the application of an external network.

I have in inetpub\wwwrooot files: clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml

I saw now that even in intranet service is not found in the published application and port 8080. The WSDL opens normally!

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

thank you

Comment: Have you configured/checked the Firewall?

Comment: Yes , I have configured the firewall with the following rules :
HTTP: Entry - Port 8080
SILVERLIGHT: Entry - Port 4502-4534

I saw now that even in intranet service is not found in the published application and port 8080 . The WSDL opens normally!